# How can I set a progress bar that shows the progress of the installation/update in install4j?

Tags: progress-bar, install4j

I saw there is a "display progress" screen and a "set the progress bar" action but none of them is visible while running the executable. 
Both solutions would be convenient because I want to see that there is something happening when the service takes to long...
Is there ay special setting that should be used for that?

Answer (score 0):

The "Set the progress bar" action configures an existing progress bar on the current screen. For example, if you add the action to the "Display progress screen" and set its "Type of change" property to "Set indeterminate", then an indeterminate progress will be shown during any subsequent actions for that screen.

The same works for the "Installation" screen or for any form screen that contains a "Progress display" form component.